# How to get WebRTC to connect to peers?

Tags: webrtc, stun, rtcpeerconnection

I'm a little confused. On this MDN page it says the following (emphasis mine) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/icecandidate_event

> An icecandidate event is sent to an RTCPeerConnection  when an RTCIceCandidate has been added to the target as a result of calling RTCPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(). This event handler **should transmit the candidate to the remote peer** so that the remote peer can add it its set of remote candidates.

The only example I could find that uses a STUN server is webrtc/samples trickle-ice https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/. My STUN server appears to work.

It will list my tcp and udp ports. However when I have IceTransports value set to relay I always get an empty list

If I want three users to visit my page and talk to eachother using RTCDataChannel how do they detect and connect to eachother?

Answer (score 0):

You need a *signaling server* to exchange the offer, answer and candidates. A STUN servers is not a signaling server, its only purpose is to find out your own public IP address.

Comment: That's a little disappointing. What's typically used? I've never use one and I suspect websockets is the thing to use?